# How can I properly use for loop in def?

Tags: python, function, for-loop

```
def kolas(lst, n):
    for i in range(0, len(lst)):
        e = []
        x = lst[i] % n
        e.append(x)
    return x
```

I noticed that for loop doesn't affect in def() - **i** is only assigned by the first value of the list. Does exist funcion like for loop that affects in def()?

Comment: what do you mean *loop doesn't affect in def()*? Please show a sample of your input, your output, and what is your **expected** output

Comment: You probably wanted to `return e`, not x

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For each iteration of `i` `e` gets reassigned to an empty list. Move the `e = []` before the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use foreach interation for this

```py
def kolas(lst, n):
    e = [] # Notice that we don't want to create it each time, only the first time
    for i in lst: # for each element in lst
        x = i % n # i now equals to the lst value
        e.append(x) # adding it into e
    return e # Returning e
```